# Poisson random measure from a Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

I would like to show that « Poisson random processes » and « Poisson random measures » are the same objects. More precisely, suppose that $N_t$ is a Poisson random process with intensity $\lambda$ on some probability space i.e. :

- $N_t$ is an increasing right-continuous integer-valued random process such that $N_0 = 0$
- $N_t$ has independent and stationary increments
- $N_t$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$

We can identify $N_t$ with its (random) Lebesgue-Stieltjes  measure $N$, defined for any Borel set $B \subset [0,\infty)$ by
$$ N(B) = \int 1_{B}(s)\, \mathrm dN_s $$
How to prove that $N$ is a random Poisson measure with intensity $\lambda\,\mathrm ds$ in the sense that :

- Whenever $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ are disjoint Borel sets, the random variables $N(B_1),\ldots,N(B_n)$ are independent.
- Whenever $B$ has finite Lebesgue measure, $N(B)$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda \int 1_B(s)\,\mathrm ds$.

My attempt was to prove a well-known formula about Poisson random measures : for all nonnegative Borel-measurable function $u$
$$ \mathbb E \exp \bigg\{- \int u(x)\,\mathrm dN \bigg\}  = \exp \bigg\{- \int (1-e^{-u})\,\mathrm d\mu\bigg\} $$ where $\mu$ denotes the intensity measure, here $\mathrm d\mu =  \lambda\,\mathrm ds$. I was able to prove  this formula  for $u$ piecewise continuous with compact support... but I don't know how to go further.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the limits of those integrals ?  The independence of the $N(B_i)$ you can show by assuming the $B_i$ are all disjoint *intervals* because intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: These are integrals over $(0,\infty)$. Well, I thought of writing down a proof using Dynkin's theorem, but that does not seem so obvious afterwards.

Comment: Eugene B. Dynkin, being one of the greatest probabilists of all times, has certainly proved not just one theorem. Please be more clear and show in detail where you got stuck.

Comment: Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem if you prefer.

Comment: What exactly makes you think this is not applicable to show independence of the $N(B_i)$ when $B_i$ are intervals ?

Comment: Somewhere in the proof, I need something like « if $X,Y$ are two random variables (on a same probability space) independent from a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$, then $(X,Y)$ is independent from $\mathcal G$ » but I think it's wrong.

Comment: Teachers also say « oh well, it's obvious because semi-open intervals generate the Borel $\sigma$-algrebra » and leave it as an exercise. When I went into details, this problem turned out to be more complicated than I expected. Everyone says it is obvious, but I can't find a proof on my own nor anywhere else.

Comment: You show exactly the right attitude. Please read my posted answer critically.

Answer (score 1):

***Partial Answer***

Let's write
$$
\Delta N_t=N_t-N_{t-}
$$
for the jump of $N$ at $t$. For each bounded set $B\subset[0,\infty)$ the Poisson process $N$ has only finitely many jumps in $t\in B$. Further,
$$
\Delta N_{t_1},...,\Delta N_{t_n}
$$
are independent for each finite set $\{t_1,...,t_n\}$ because $N$ has independent increments.

When $B$ is a bounded Borel set then we note that
$$
N(B)=\sum_{s\in B}\Delta N_s.
$$
is a finite sum of jumps. This should imply that
$$
N(B_1),....,N(B_n)
$$
are independent for each collection of disjoint *bounded* Borel sets $B_1,...,B_n$.

Comment: Okay, and since inter-arrivals times are exponentially distributed, $N(B)$ has a Poisson distribution, right ? So my formula holds for measurable simple functions $u$ with bounded support, and then I may use some monotone approximation argument to conclude ?

Comment: I am now adopting the same attitude as you rightfully do with your teachers. Please spell out these proofs in full detail and I will review.

Comment: I will write all the details and come back later when I'm done.