# Is "(measurable) process" sometimes used to mean a random variable in the literature?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm reading "Random measures, theory and applications" by Kallenberg and I'm getting confused what is exactly meant by the word "process" in his book. Here are two examples of statements (unrelated to eachother, but both referring some undefined process). In both cases $S$ is some Borel space and $\hat S $ is a certain subset of the $\sigma$ field.

> For any random measure $\eta$ and measurable process $X \geqslant 0$ on $S$, the integral process $\xi = X \cdot \eta$ exists and is measurable on $\hat S$. When $\xi$ is locally finite, it is again a random measure on $S$.

> Given a process $\eta \geqslant 0$ on a generating ring $\mathcal U \subset \hat S$, there exists a random measure $\xi$ on $S$ with $\xi U = \eta U$ almost surely, for all $U \in \mathcal U$ iff
>
> 1. $\eta (A \cup B)= \eta A + \eta B$ for disjoint $A,B$
> 2. $\eta A_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability as $A_n \rightarrow \emptyset$ along $\mathcal U$

Usually i've encountered random processes defined as a collection of random variables indexed by some real number $t$, but it seems this is not what the author is referring to. I'm a bit confused here, it seems like sometimes a process is a random variable, but in the second statement it's acting on sets $A,B$?

EDIT: Here is one example the author gives, right after the first statement I quoted.

> It may be surprising that the joint distribution of $X$ and $\eta$ may not determine the distribution $\xi = X \eta$. For a simple counterexample consider $\xi = \delta_{\tau}$ where $\tau = U(0,1)$, and let $X_t = 1\{ t = \tau\}$ and $Y_t=0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Then $X,Y$ are measurable with $X_t = Y_t = 0$ almost surely for every $t$, so the distributions $(X, \eta), (Y, \eta)$ are the same. But $\eta X = 1$ and $\eta Y = 0$.

So by my understanding in the above example $S = [0,1]$ and then $X,Y$ are families of nonnegative random variables indexed over $S$. This makes sense, but then I'm still confused how such a process would act on sets as in the second statement i quoted. I.e. what is the meaning of $\eta A + \eta B$ ?

Comment: "Process" is just aword that can mean other things than those indexed with $t$. Keep reading in the hope that Mr Kallenberg gives some concrete examples. If not: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4453275/949989) might help.

Comment: $X$ is no RV, it's a process indexed over $S$, i.e. a random function from $S$ to $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Tobsn What does random function mean here? Is it a family of RV indexed over $S$? And if so then what is $\eta A$ for a set $A$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. He actually does give a concrete example related to the first quote, i edited my question with it now.

Comment: No offense, but my feeling is you are mathematically not mature enough to read this Kallenberg book. You may need to revisit some primary principles on stochastic processes before. Otherwise the lecture of Kallenberg is not going to be fun for you. 
 Anyway, $\eta$ is process on $\mathcal{U}$, not on $S$. It's therefore, if you like, a family of RVs indexed over the sets in $\mathcal{U}$.